# Use calendar week grouping on Highcharts.StockChart X-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to find a way to group my X-Axis in Highchart.StockChart by calendar weeks. There is a way to set the visible area to a "week" but i want to group all values by calendar weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting proper unit in dataGrouping.units? Take a look at the doc: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.units

Comment: Looks exactly like what I was looking for. I missed this grouping part in the documentation,somehow.